# Does Google Maps for Flash support Street-VIew?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to use Google street-view in a Flash application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no.  but as of a few weeks ago it now supports Styled Maps and Elevation Services, so while that doesn't help you, it shows that Google is constantly working on the Maps for Flash API, so street view could become a new feature at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking it into your Flash app: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#PanoramaObject